# codename one Background fetch not firing on ios

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to get my app to launch a background task using the method described here:
https://www.codenameone.com/blog/background-fetch.html

However on iOS the background update method is not being called. Seems to work fine on Android. I've added fetch to the background modes build hint, is there any other build hints I need to add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/codenameone-discussions/Q4pwB28AG5I/tIsWgnOBDAAJ) it is probably related to a process call in `stop()` or a different background process, modification to the plist etc.